# Query different table based on input parameter

Tags: sql, parameters

I have a pretty simple stored procedure that allows a user to display different data based on dates.  I have 2 parameters, a start date and end date.  So basically, the query returns data based on a date range.  Depending on those dates, I need to query a different table, however.  So if the user wants data from 1/1/2015 - 1/31/2015, its one table.  If they want data from 2/1/2015 - 2/28/2015, its a different table.  They are also allowed to cross, so 1/1/2015 - 2/28/2015.

```
SELECT * 
FROM shipments 
JOIN costs ON shipment.shipmentid = cost.shipmentid 
WHERE ship_date between @sdate and @edate
```

If the ship_date was before 2/1/2015, then I need to pull from a different cost table.

I hope this makes sense. Would dynamic SQL be the way to go?

Comment: For easy handling you could create a "view", using `UNION` to combine both tables to a certain format. Then, you always could query the view, leaving the resolution up to mysql. But it would be better to *migrate* old data to the new data format!

Answer (score 0):

You'd just want to dynamically create the query with the back-end programming language of your choice.  There's no pure-SQL way of accomplishing that.

Answer (score 0):

The most simple way would be something in the function such as:

```
if @sDate <'some_date'

@tableName = 'first_table';

else 

@tableName = 'other_table';

end if;


ELECT * 
FROM @tableName
JOIN costs ON shipment.shipmentid = cost.shipmentid 
WHERE ship_date between @sdate and @edate
```

You could also do a union on the table, however that might have cost issues (not sure how big the tables are).

Comment: I tried this and it keeps telling me I have to declare @tablename in my select statement.

Comment: Is it case sensitive? you put above "@tablename" when it was declared as "@tableName"

Answer (score 0):

I avoid dynamically building SQL in a SP, because in takes away your "precompiled" benefit.  `Union`is really the best path, as dognose mentioned.
There's always more than one way to do it, and you could experiment for performance; but something similar to this should work:

```
SELECT * FROM shipments
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT col1,col2,col3,shipment_id FROM costs
    WHERE ship_date > "2/1/2015" 
    UNION
    SELECT col1,col2,col3,shipment_id FROM costs_old
    WHERE ship_date <= "2/1/2015" 
) AS costs_union ON shipments.shipmentid = costs_union.shipmentid
WHERE shipments.ship_date between @sdate and @edate
```

Depending on the size of those costs tables you might want WHERE clauses in the unioned query to make them smaller...

Comment: I tried this and it is giving me 2 records for each occurrence of the shipment, one for each match on the shipment_id in the shipments table.

Comment: OK, sorry, I don't fully understand your schema.  Since you know the "hard cut-off date", just put that into the unioned query: 'SELECT col1,col2,col3,shipment_id FROM costs WHERE ship_date > "2/1/2015" UNION ...'